# build.xml in Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ant, build

What is the file `build.xml`?

I was wondering if it is a possibility to import this project in Eclipse or Netbeans using this `build.xml`. I tried to import the project but I get some errors since one part is created using J2ME and the other J2SE and I guess this file should be the configuration.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`build.xml` usually is an [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) build script.

It contains information necessary to build the project to produce the desired output, be it Javadocs, a compiled project, or a JAR file.

I believe Eclipse has ant built-in, so it should be possible to execute the `build.xml` by choosing "Run As..." and "Ant Build".

The `build.xml` file, if it is an ant script, is not used to import the project into an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans. A build script is used to build the project (or produce some desired output) rather than an mechanism for importing the project into an IDE.

Comment: Where is the file located?

Comment: @KarlMorrison it should be in the root directory of your project

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned by @coobird this is an ant build file. Although IDEs such as Eclipse and Netbeans have ant support built-in, it is also possible to run ant from the command-line and this may be the simplest way to get started if the project has been well created.

See http://ant.apache.org/
for docs.

If you want to try this approach, install ant, `cd` to the directory with `build.xml` and issue

```
ant
```

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse can be told to build using an Ant script, but [you can also use Ant itself](http://ant.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

build.xml file is an Ant(Apache) script.
you can find more information on Ant & build.xml [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

In java project build.xml file is used write the ant script. 
And from that ant script you can generate war file and can deploy on Tomcat server