# Jenkins integration with GitHub #Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, github, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

i have been trying to integrate Jenkins with GibHub repository where all my selenium scripts are located. Just for automated testing at particular time. I did some research and it's possible by creating ANT(build.xml) file of your project. i was trying to create one by project>export>general>ant in eclipse but it doesn't show up in my workspace. Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't done enough configuration settings to auto generate build.xml .In my opinion you should use already written build.xml for your project.
Even you want to learn about ant and build.xml then I think this is the good place to get valuable knowledge. [Click Here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html)

[Any way to generate ant build.xml file automatically from Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185921/any-way-to-generate-ant-build-xml-file-automatically-from-eclipse)

[build.xml in Java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551107/build-xml-in-java-project)